# How to download css without corrupting the play button images

Tags: html, css, video

I am trying to make my own custom video player(http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/videodrome/videojs/).

Eveyrthing works perfectly fine! However, I tried to download the stylesheeet below:

`<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.9.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">`

and upload it on my own domain (//mydomain.com/4.9.0/video-js.css), and use that uploaded css instead. However, every time I do that, the play button, mute button, pause button, full screen button is not visible anymore. What am i doing wroing?

Comment: It's likely these buttons are images defined in the Css file and that they are not on your server when it's trying to load them.

Comment: No, I tried to edit all scr for images and still got no result, just take a look at the css